# Python - how can i work locally on a module that i'm also using on other scripts?

Tags: python

I've created a Python module called `chain_data` and pushed it to GitHub. I can easily install it on other machines using pip. I also have a simple Python script that imports and uses the module installed in the site-packages folder.

Here's the problem: whenever i encounter a bug or issue with the module while using it in my script, i have to go through a long process: first, i make the necessary edits to the module in my local repository, then i commit and push those changes to the github repository and finally i upgrade the installed version of `chain_data` with pip before i can go back to using it in my script. It's quite time-consuming and slows down my development.

Is there a way to speed up this process? Can I see the changes i make to my local version of the module instantly without going through all those steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you do not plan to wipeout your environment you can install your package [with editable mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html).

```
pip install -e chain_data
```

That way you can modify the source directly and use the newest version. When you are satisfied you can copy all content where `chain_data` is installed from to directory with git.